# Keep Size Image with Ground Overlay in Google Map

Tags: java, android, image, google-maps, size

I'm new in Android and I'm building an app. My problem is that when I want to put my own image in google map app using Ground Overlay.

But When I put my images, I can't keep the size, it very small and when I zoom it is the real size. What I would like to have it's when I zoom it keep the same size.

For example in Booking App, The "H" image is always at the same size (Airbnb had the same also).

Here is my code:

```
  @Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    // Register a listener to respond to clicks on GroundOverlays.
    map.setOnGroundOverlayClickListener(this);

    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(NEWARK, 11));

    mImages.clear();
    mImages.add(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.newark_nj_1922));
    mImages.add(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.newark_prudential_sunny));
    mImages.add(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.logo_franprix));
    //Resources res = getResources();
    //Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_logo_franprix);

    // Add a small, rotated overlay that is clickable by default
    // (set by the initial state of the checkbox.)
    mGroundOverlayRotated = map.addGroundOverlay(new GroundOverlayOptions().image(mImages.get(2)).anchor(0, 1)
            .position(new LatLng(48.886517, 2.37105), 300f,300f));
```

I hope that you could help me, thank you very much.

Comment: You may need yo use a `Marker` instead of a `GroundOverlay`

Comment: But I would like to click on an image instead of a marker, I want to put an image that keep his real size and click on it to have an info window

Comment: Then your best option is to use a Marker with a custom icon

Comment: @RamziHouhou: did you find a solution for this ? I have the same issue